# Unserialize() Error after moving the installation directory

Tags: views, 7, caching

I have just added a repository from git to my Eclipse IDE , setup the database with proper imports and dumps, however getting

```
Error at offset in cache.inc
```

Any suggestions what went wrong and solution.[image: Error at localhost/insight]

Comment: You getting this message on page load ?

Comment: yes as i migrate to localhost/insight (insight is the installation name directory ) , getting this error

Answer (score 3):

After making a back-up of current db,

Try this in phpMyAdmin or mysql console.

```
TRUNCATE `cache`;
TRUNCATE `cache_block`;
TRUNCATE `cache_bootstrap`;
TRUNCATE `cache_field`;
TRUNCATE `cache_filter`;
TRUNCATE `cache_form`;
TRUNCATE `cache_image`;
TRUNCATE `cache_libraries`;
TRUNCATE `cache_menu`;
TRUNCATE `cache_page`;
TRUNCATE `cache_path`;
TRUNCATE `cache_rules`;
TRUNCATE `cache_token`;
TRUNCATE `cache_views`;
TRUNCATE `cache_views_data`;
```

Comment: Hope it doesnt breaks the site?

Comment: @PreritMohan, please make a backup of `db`